# Disconnected clients remaining online on Openfire server with websockets

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I'm using Openfire as XMPP server and I added the [websocket plugin](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/websocket/readme.html) to it in order to improve some chat features (i.e. file transfer).

Communication via xmpp among my web clients works fine but there is an issue on client network disconnections or changes.

In fact in those cases **disconnected clients still remain online in the server, even if a timeout in the idle connection policy is set**.

No ping is sent to the clients, so openfire never checks if client connections are active or not.

I've seen that an issue is still open: https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/OF-963

Is there a workaround to avoid disconnected clients remaining online on Openfire server with websockets?

Answer (score 0):

I use older version, exactly 4.0.2 I think for my Openfire installation as this BUG is not fixed yet.

This is the reason why messages are sent from another client and lost, cause first client appear as online and in reality it is not regardless the time interval you set in Openfire config after which it will disconnect clients.